# how to make a button responsive on mobile

Tags: wordpress, css, button, css-float

I have been searching all over the internet how to fix this. Basically I need the button on the right side on desktop view. See below:
[chrome view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teuJY.jpg)

But when you resize it or viewed on mobile devices, it should be in full width but I cannot do it. see below:

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/534BY.jpg)

This is a sticky or scrolling menu as well. Here are my codes:

```
/* call button small*/
.buttonfloat-small{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
z-index: 99;
display:block;
width:100%;
margin: auto;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since that code should do the job, there must be something else blocking it. Resize browser and check with the Inspector (right click the button) and you most likely will find it

Comment: For us to help, you need to post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: @LGSon thank you! how about this:  http://imgur.com/a/RH1lT

Comment: Well, that is an image of some code and not a _working code snippet_, so we can test it

Comment: @LeeDev try replicating the issue with the least code possible on something like codepen.io

Comment: Yea we need some code in order to really help you further, if the website is live or publicly accessible somewhere, then you could also post that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using:

```
.buttonfloat-small div a.fl-button {width:100%}
.buttonfloat-small div {margin:0!important}
```

OR by directly targeting the nodes:

```
a.fl-button {width:100%}
.fl-node-5907a486bf15a > .fl-module-content {margin:0}
```

Which will make it look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epv0B.png

Side Note: The important override on the first div is to remove the 20px right margin from the ".fl-node-5907a486bf15a > .fl-module-content". Calling on it directly doesn't require the important tag (hence both examples).

This has to be put into your Media Queries to make it only appear full width when resized, like:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .buttonfloat-small div a.fl-button {width:100%}
    .buttonfloat-small div {margin:0!important}
}
```

Changing the text to change from Call Us On to Call Now, I'd personally do with JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $(".buttonfloat-small div a.fl-button span.fl-button-text"),
        resize = function() {
            if (window.matchMedia('(max-width:767px)').matches) {
                button.html("Call Now 0330 838 1828");
            } else {
                button.html("Call Us On 0330 838 1828");
            }
        };
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
```

This will check if the width it 767 and if so then it will show Call Now, else it will show Call us and will also change when the window is resized.

Here's a JSFiddle showing the effects: https://jsfiddle.net/awwy5ram/1/

Let me know if you require more assistance!

Comment: thank you! however, my problem is that the small button needs to be small on desktop browsers and will only show full width when you viewed it on mobile devices. desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teuJY.jpg and then for the mobile view like your screenshot

Comment: Oh you'll have to put this in your Media Queries then, which you normally already have in place. I've updated my main answer.

Comment: OMG! you are a star! can I give 5 stars or a beer? Thank you @Rafaël De Jongh !

Comment: Cheers mate, feel free to accept the answer and if you really want to send me a beer you can always send a couple of bucks my way (https://paypal.me/RafaelDeJongh). Either way thanks and I'm glad I could help you!

Comment: Last one @Rafaël De Jongh , same on media queries code you gave me if viewed also on mobile, how can I remove the radius on the top left and top right? thanks!

Comment: Oh you can add "border-radius:0" to your .buttonfloat-small div a.fl-button (normally) your current site doesn't have any border radius anymore, so I think you solved this yourself? Let me know if you need more help ;) Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as correct!

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked. Sorry to bug you but for the text inside the button "Call Us On 0330..." can I changed it to "Call Now" text only when viewed on mobile?

Comment: That wouldn't directly be possible with only CSS (other than using the :before content tag excluding the call text from the DOM). Or by using two fields where one has the Call Us On and is displayed above > 768 pixels and another with Call Now that is only displayed below < 768. But then you've got a duplicate DOM element which isn't the best choice either.

The more user friendly way would be to use JavaScript/JQuery to state if the window width is < than 768 then the innerHTML would change from Call Us On to Call Now.

Comment: Added the JS part to my main answer!

Comment: Thank you again! you are so helpful friend! okay, my last hurdle, I did not put the classes in 1 element, so I am hard time modifying it. Basically what I need to test is that when I view the element , I only change .buttonfloat-small to .buttonfloat-big (or vice versa) and it should display

Comment: Oh if you have it like that, then you can use display:none/display:block whenever the media query is in place. So default you set .buttonfloat-big to display:block and -small to display:none. And in your MediaQuery you flip those that .buttonfloat-big is on display:none and -small on display:block.

Comment: hi sorry quite difficult to understand, can you perhaps create the code for me? I would really really appreciate it. You have helped me alot! @Rafaël De Jongh

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question, as looking at your site now, it appears to work fine? Or are you referring to have the jquery code to also work on both the buttonfloat-big and buttonfloat-small?

Comment: Yes, the  buttonfloat-big and buttonfloat-small should be in one element. Example when I am changing the code from buttonfloat-small  http://imgur.com/a/YZLNS to "buttonfloat-big" on the inspect element it should change to that class http://imgur.com/a/cvCJR @Rafaël De Jongh

Comment: Hmm, I'm not exactly sure what you're after however. If you just want control over both the same css then you could just write .buttonfloat-big, .buttonfloat-small{//code here} but if it's something else you're after then I'm unsure what you're looking for actually